# C# Fill out a Rectangle with points

Tags: c#, draw, brushes

Hi
I want to Fill out a Rectangle. Normally i can use:

```
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

But I don't want to fill it completly out with a green color, I want to fill it out with points
So i want it: One point black, one point green, one point black...
Can you help me
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use a [`HatchBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchbrush.aspx) with [`HatchStyle.Percent50`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchstyle.asp), instead of your normal green brush, like so:

```
Brush b = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Percent50, Color.Green, Color.Black);
g.FillRectangle(b, x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

For a demo of the other hatchstyles, see [the following demo](http://www.dotnetcharting.com/gallery/view.aspx?id=HatchPalette).